# Searching users by email with FQL

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql

Took me quite a while to determine why my fql search wasn't working in javascript.  After finally discovering the old REST API page to test FQL queries I discovered that I cannot perform this search because the 'email' column is "not indexable".

Is there any way I can execute a query like this?

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE email="user@email.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a user search against the graph API. It's not available via FQL.

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=zuck@fb.com&type=user&access_token=...

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the graph API version, was hoping I didn't have to use that though, FQL is much more convenient.  But, as I've learned from the past couple months of working the the Facebook APIs, if they don't want you to do something, you're not going to be able to

Comment: That is the only way to get it though. Sorry.